# Entity Framework with ASP.NET one-to-many relation causes NullReference error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, relationship

In my database I have two entities: DbStatus and DbTask

```
public class DbStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DbTask> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class DbTask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual DbStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

In the `OnModelCreating` method, I establish the relation with the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbStatus>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Tasks)
            .WithOne(t => t.Status)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.StatusId);
```

I also add some sample data in this method, setting the `StatusId` of newly created `DbTasks`.

Problem is, when I try to access the `Status` name of the `DbTask` using

```
task.Status.Name
```

I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Can anyone help me how to set up the relation properly?

**IMPORTANT**

For anyone reading this, the quickest solution (and the one fulfilling task-specific criterias) for this was provided Rob. However, you should read and implement the solution provided by Steve Py, for the reasons they also describe in their answer!

Comment: How are you getting "task" in your last code block?

Comment: With the usual OnModelCreating method I get a DbContext, which has a List of DbTasks. In another class I access this list and the DbTasks in it. "task" is a DbTask. I should also mention that I can access every property of DbTask successfully, only the Status throws the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting your list of `DbTasks` from the database, you need to tell it to include the child `Status` objects.

Try something like this:

```
var tasks = dbContext.DbTasks
    .Include(t => t.Status)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a FK on an entity does not automatically cause that related entity to be loaded. When working with navigation properties I recommend avoiding declaring FK fields in entities and using shadow properties to avoid issues like this.

To update a status on a DbTask:

```
public ActionResult MarkTaskComplete(int taskId)
{
    var completeStatus = _context.Statuses.Single(x => x.StatusId = Statuses.Complete);
    // TODO: Validation that user can update task etc.
    var task = _context.Tasks
        .Include(x => x.Status)
        .Single(x => x.TaskId == taskId);
    task.Status = completeStatus;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { success = true; status = task.Status.Name } );
}
```

The issue with FK fields is that the behaviour can differ depending on whether you use the navigation property or the FK, and whether the navigation property is eager loaded or not. From the perspective of the Task, there are two sources of truth for the current Status, some code might check task.StatusId while others use task.Status.StatusId. These values could differ depending on one being updated without the other.

While this can mean a trip to the DB to fetch a status, fetching rows by ID is extremely fast, and also provides a validation that your methods are only using legal values.

Comment: I see what you mean and I think you are right; but unfortunately this is a school task, and it says that I have to build the database in the OnModelCreatingMethod, where I cannot access the lists (it throws an exception since the framework is currently building them), therefore I cannot set the relation in your explicit way. 
However, I will write down your solution and use it in my future projects, because as I said, I understand the issues you raised.
Honest thanks for your answer